# Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Light.Base.DropDownItem.Spinner'

Tags: android

If I use

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
```

inside build.gradle as dependencies I am getting error

Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Light.Base.DropDownItem.Spinner'.